# Case not summing correctly

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble with my query below

```
SELECT DATE(jc.`date_in`) DAY,
CASE 
WHEN jb.`modified_fr` <> 0 THEN ROUND(SUM(jb.`modified_fr`),1)
ELSE ROUND(SUM(jd.`fr1`),1)  
END AS AmountOfHoursBooked
,ds.`name` AS dealership, d.`name` AS Department 
FROM jobcard jc
LEFT JOIN job jb
ON jc.`id` = jb.`jobcard`
LEFT JOIN job_definition jd
ON jb.`job_definition` = jd.`id`
LEFT JOIN department d
ON jc.`department` = d.`id`
JOIN dealership ds
ON d.`dealership` = ds.`id`
WHERE MONTH(jc.`date_in`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(jc.`date_in`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
AND jd.`fr1` <> 0
AND jc.`status` <> 5
GROUP BY DATE(jc.`date_in`),jc.`department`;
```

what i need it to do is if the case comes back true it should use that modified fr instead of the original fr from jb table ?

what am I missing ?

thanks in advance

Comment: what is your trouble

Comment: Change your case statements as `ROUND(SUM(CASE 
WHEN jb.`modified_fr` <> 0 THEN jb.`modified_fr`
ELSE jd.`fr1`  
END),1)`

Comment: You tried: `ROUND(SUM(CASE 
WHEN jb.modified_fr <> 0 THEN jb.modified_fr
ELSE jd.fr1
END), 1)`?

Comment: Thank you so much guys !! works like a bomb !!